BigCommerce v8 CLI will not build production files
I've recently updated the BigCommerce CLI for a project not worked on for a while. After the update not SCSS files would compile. Eventually got files compiling using node v18.15.0 which is in the BigCommerce docs for this update.
After running stencil push to deploy the files I get errors like below. The error isModuleDeclaration has been deprecated, please migrate to isImportOrExportDeclaration
at isModuleDeclaration ` seems to be down to the node version, but i'm using whats being instructed in the docs.
I've ran npm i to make sure all dependancies are up to date, but thats not helped.
Does anyone know what the issue is here / how to fix?
Theme task Started...

ok -- Schema Translations Parsing Finished
ok -- Language Files Parsing Finished
ok -- Theme Schema Building Finished
ok -- SCSS Parsing Finished
ok -- Template Parsing Finished
isModuleDeclaration has been deprecated, please migrate to isImportOrExportDeclaration
at isModuleDeclaration (/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/node_modules/@babel/types/lib/validators/generated/index.js:2748:35)
at PluginPass.Program (/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/node_modules/babel-plugin-lodash/lib/index.js:102:44)
Error parsing bundle asset "/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/assets/dist/theme-bundle.chunk.0.js": no such file
Error parsing bundle asset "/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/assets/dist/theme-bundle.chunk.1.js": no such file
Error parsing bundle asset "/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/assets/dist/theme-bundle.chunk.10.js": no such file
Error parsing bundle asset "/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/assets/dist/theme-bundle.chunk.11.js": no such file
Error parsing bundle asset "/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/assets/dist/theme-bundle.chunk.12.js": no such file
Error parsing bundle asset "/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/assets/dist/theme-bundle.chunk.13.js": no such file
Error parsing bundle asset "/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/assets/dist/theme-bundle.chunk.14.js": no such file
Error parsing bundle asset "/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/assets/dist/theme-bundle.chunk.2.js": no such file
Error parsing bundle asset "/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/assets/dist/theme-bundle.chunk.6.js": no such file
Error parsing bundle asset "/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/assets/dist/theme-bundle.chunk.7.js": no such file
Error parsing bundle asset "/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/assets/dist/theme-bundle.chunk.8.js": no such file
Error parsing bundle asset "/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/assets/dist/theme-bundle.chunk.9.js": no such file
Error parsing bundle asset "/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/assets/dist/theme-bundle.head_async.js": no such file
Error parsing bundle asset "/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/assets/dist/theme-bundle.main.js": no such file
Error parsing bundle asset "/Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/assets/dist/theme-bundle.polyfills.js": no such file
No bundles were parsed. Analyzer will show only original module sizes from stats file.
Webpack Bundle Analyzer saved report to /Users/example/Documents/Clients/exampleClient/exampleProject/assets/dist/report.html
ERROR in theme-bundle.chunk.0.js from Terser
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Fixed this issue using npm update!
Deleting node_modules and npm install didn't work...
